# ReferenceError: Translator is not defined in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to add shopping cart price rule by going through **Admin -> Promotions -> Add New Rule.**

But when I try to apply condition by clicking on "Condition" tab and clicking on plus icon, it generates following error in console:

```
ReferenceError: Translator is not defined
```

Please see following screenshot. I tried to disable some extensions but not solved. Hopefully someone hint me about it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if **js/mage/translate.js** is loading before rules js/mage/adminhtml/rules.js or not.

Comment: I have checked it and it is loading before js/mage/adminhtml/rules.js